# ubuntu 20.04 wayland fractional scaling only works with Gnome apps

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, wayland

I am using fractional scaling on ubuntu 20.04(loged in with wayland, intel GPU), fractional scaling only works with Gnome apps(gnome-terminal, gnome-setting) on dual monitors, other apps like chrome or atom don't scale fractionally as is shown below: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip3hu.png)

Fractional scaling causes screen tearing if logging in with x windows on my pc, apps do scale well with X11 session though. So is there any solution to make all apps scale fractionally on wayland?